# Traversal of basic linked list using Java 8 Lambda and Streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Are there anyway to traverse a basic Linked List using Java 8 lambda? Lets if below is signature of a Node

```
public class ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode next;
  ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

and this is my test data:

```
    ListNode node1 = new ListNode(90);
    node1.next = new ListNode(200);
    node1.next.next = new ListNode(300);
    node1.next.next.next = new ListNode(400);
```

Is it possible to traverse using Java 8 lambda/ stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Java 9: `Stream.iterate(firstNode, Objects::nonNull, node -> node.next) ...`

Comment: @Holger Please don't place answers as comments.

Answer (score 2):

First note that the [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class is already available in the JDK, and directly provides the `.stream()` method. I would recommend using this standard implementation if possible.

If you still want to use your custom class `ListNode`, a good way to obtain a stream from it is to :

1. make `ListNode` implement `java.lang.Iterable` interface,
2. call `StreamSupport.stream(listNodeInstance.spliterator(), false)`

Answer (score 1):

in Java 8 we have only `Stream::iterate` with 2 arguments: the initial element and a function to produce a new element from previous one, but you have to make this stream finite and one way of doing this is by using `Stream::limit` and by passing linked list size (which you should have even in a basic implementation):

```
Stream.iterate(node1, ListNode::getNext)
      .limit(4) //linked list size
      .forEach(n -> {
          System.out.println(n.val);
      });
```